# Blackberry simulator screen refresh

Tags: windows-7, blackberry-simulator

When I use the stock Blackberry simulator, the screen seems to NOT repaint when I interact with the virtual device.  I have to minimize/restore the simulator app for the screen to get repainted, but it should have repainted on its own.

This only happens on my Windows 7 machine, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in the simulator disable graphics acceleration

menu view-> graphics accelleration -> off.

this does the trick.

Francesco
http://www.synesthesia.it